# Can we remove queued transaction in geth pool (PoA)?

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

Is there a way to limit time of queued transaction or remove them ?

I am using PoA network (Geth)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove transactions by shutting down the node and deleting `transactions.rlp` in your geth folder.

As for limiting transactions, like your previous comment mentions `--txpool.lifetime` controls the amount of time a txn will sit in the queue. You may set it to be more or less than default value of 3 hours like so: `--txpool.lifetime 0h5m0s`

Comment: and what happens after the "0h5m0s" ? what the rpc client got as a response?

Comment: I set --txpool.lifetime 0h0m3s but it didn't work for me

Comment: This only affects on the txpool.queued txns.

Comment: it didnt affects anything

Comment: can anyone help?